# Less response Time from webserver

Tags: java, android, http, wamp

I had developed an app in android that take some data from a database stored on a web server and draw a GUI according to data captured.The problem is that when i run app on localhost using (WAMP) it creates GUI in 2 seconds but when i connect it to the webserver it takes almost 7 to 10 minutes.I am astonished what could be the possible reason behind this.
I had not used any ASync class in my code.I had used httpclient.execute stuff to connect to web server and JSON pasring.I hope you understand.Please tell me what could be the reason behind less response time.

Comment: So if you haven't used an AsyncTask in your code, I assume you would get an ANR message if it does indeed take 7-10 minutes. Are the data payloads you are referencing the same size? What size? are we talking 1k, 1mb, 1gb files here?

Comment: The size is  in KBs say 5 to 10KB because i am only getting string from the database.

Comment: Are you sure it is network latency you are seeing? I mean is the database a fresh install? Can you from your localhost do something like a wget to the webserver to measure if it is your webserver's side or if the client is being very slow? This seems really unlikely unless you have like some emulator simulation setting on that is like 1 bit per second.

Comment: when I use WAMP it gets the data very fast from localhost but on webserver like phpnet.us and 000webhost.com it behaves very slowly.Can you advice me of some software through which i can  measure the response time from a website on android?

Comment: I would just use wget or a web browser to see if I could hit the remote server and get adequate responses from it. It could be that there is a lot of latency between those machines, or that they are really overtasked. Or you could just write a simple program in your language of choice that actually makes the http requests in the way your device will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing is whats the speed of your internet ? if your connection is slow that could be the reason. and other thing is you might be doing all gui processing on client via request only. my suggtion is have screens ready and fill data via things like json/REST stuff. for others i can only tell you once you show some code.

Comment: Internet speed is fine..my app access a php page that returns a JSON object that i parse in my App